# QString remove last characters

Tags: qt, qstring

How to remove /Job from /home/admin/job0/Job

```
QString name = "/home/admin/job0/Job"
```

I want to remove last string after"/"

Comment: Since you seem to be playing with directories, you can use `QDir` class and its [`QDir::cdUp`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#cdUp) method.

Comment: Is this a qt question, or a C++ question? What have you tried so far? Do you want to remove just the _last string after "/"_ or _remove /Job_ including the slash?

Comment: Maybe you can use `QFileInfo` for this task.

Comment: `QDir::cdUp` won't work if the parent directory does not exist. Better to use `QFileInfo(name).dir().path()`, which doesn't check for existence.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Find last slash with [QString::lastIndexOf](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#lastIndexOf). 
After that get substring with [QString::left](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#left) till the position of the last slash occurrence

```
QString name = "/home/admin/job0/Job";
int pos = name.lastIndexOf(QChar('/'));
qDebug() << name.left(pos);
```

This will print:

```
"/home/admin/job0"
```

You should check **int pos** for **-1** to be sure the slash was found at all.

To include last slash in output add **+1** to the founded position

```
qDebug() << name.left(pos+1);
```

Will output:

```
"/home/admin/job0/"
```

Comment: i think your solution is the common one :D

Comment: You don't need to check if pos ==-1 becouse if  or less than zero the entire string is will be returned

Answer (score 23):

You have [QString::chop()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#chop) for the case when you already know how many characters to remove.
It is same as `QString::remove()`, just works from the back of string.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe easiest to understand for later readers would probably be:

```
QString s("/home/admin/job0/Job");
s.truncate(s.lastIndexOf(QChar('/'));
qDebug() << s;
```

as the code literaly says what you intended.

Comment: there's one problem in some cases: If the string contains no slash, it is cleared completely

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
QString s("/home/admin/job0/Job");
s.remove(QRegularExpression("\\/(?:.(?!\\/))+$"));
// s is "/home/admin/job0" now
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Qt upper than 6 and sure that "/" constains in your word you should use `QString::first(qsizetype n) const` function instead `QString::left(qsizetype n) const`

Example:

```
QString url= "/home/admin/job0/Job"
QString result=url.first(lastIndexOf(QChar('/')));
```

If you run these code:

```
QElapsedTimer timer;
timer.start();
for (int j=0; j<10000000; j++)
{
    QString name = "/home/admin/job0/Job";
    int pos = name.lastIndexOf("/");
    name.left(pos);
}
qDebug() << "left method" << timer.elapsed() << "milliseconds";
timer.start();
for (int j=0; j<10000000; j++)
{
    QString name = "/home/admin/job0/Job";
    int pos = name.lastIndexOf(QChar('/'));
    name.first(pos);
}
qDebug() << "frist method" << timer.elapsed() << "milliseconds";
```

Results:

left method 10034 milliseconds

frist method 8098 milliseconds

Answer (score -2):

sorry for replying to this post after 4 years, but I have (I think) the most efficient answer.
You can use

```
qstr.remove(0, 1); //removes the first character
qstr.remove(1, 1); //removes the last character
```

Thats everything you have to do, to delete characters ONE BY ONE (first or last) from a QString, until 1 character remains.

Comment: How does this solves the problem of the OP, he wants the end of the string, not the beginning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).